# Is there a relation between ascendo and accendo?

Tags: word-comparison

I have always learnt that ascendo means to go up and accendo means to ignite. Do they even originate from the same word and if so how have they come to be as they are?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, they're two different roots. *Ascendere* is made up of the prefix *ad-* + *scandere* (first: *scando*), which means "to climb."

On the other hand, *accendere* is related to *candere* (first: *candeo*), which means "to shine" or "to glow" (like a fire).

Comment: Slight quibble: *accendere* isn't directly derived from *candēre* -- which would yield *accendēre* -- but is probably from the same Indo-European root (thus de Vaan, at least).

Comment: Good point. Edited for accuracy.